# transformation mode won't change from rotate to translate

Tags: transforms, 3d-manipulator

when I click on translate, it won't come out of rotate  mode. I can  select any object in the scene, but am stuck in rotate mode.

[image: when I click on translate, it won't come out of rotate mode. I can select any object in the scene, but am stuck in rotate mode.]

Comment: Seems odd. What happens when you press 'g' (for grab/translate mode)?

Comment: Try going from rotation to scale and then back to position.